# What is the difference between a Micro-controller and a EEPROM?

Tags: microcontroller, eeprom

What are the tasks Micro-controller are used in, compared to EEPROM?

Also for a simple Arudino, is ATmega328 the micro-controller or EEPROM?

Comment: In which cases are engines used, as compared to cars? (Seriously, did you do *any* googling followed by actual reading?)

Comment: yes i did, and I'm still confused. Is the EEPROM part of the micro-controller or not? Are they two separate chips or?

Comment: Depends. Are you distinguishing between FLASH and EEPROM?

Answer (score 3):

**EEPROM**, Electrically Erasable Programmable Read Only Memory, is typically used as a storage device for information that must survive a power-cycle of a device. An example of this is the page counter of a printer. The EEPROM does not have the ability to perform any logic, etc. It's only an array of memory bits with an addressing scheme that allows an intelligent controller to read from or write data to it.

A **microcontroller** contains the essential parts of a general-purpose computer.

> A microcontroller is a small computer (SoC) on a single integrated circuit containing a processor core, memory, and programmable input/output peripherals. Program memory in the form of Ferroelectric RAM, NOR flash or OTP ROM is also often included on chip, as well as a typically small amount of RAM. Microcontrollers are designed for embedded applications, in contrast to the microprocessors used in personal computers or other general purpose applications consisting of various discrete chips. *Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller)*.

The microcontroller may use EEPROM, either internal or external, but it is only a small part of the system.

Answer (score 1):

ATmega328 is a small computer (which includes EEPROM), and EEPROM is just a storage device.

Comment: Sorry but I'm still confused, is the EEPROM a separate component or is part of the Micro-controller?

Comment: @nicko_yuan Microcontrollers have built-in EEPROM.

Comment: I see, so Micro-controllers has CPU, system clock, Memory and Peripherals. In that case, this means the Memory side is called EEPROM?

Comment: yes then have a flash/rom of some sort, and all those things you mentioned and some ram as well.  So the memory side includes SRAM and flash/rom

Answer (score 0):

A picture paints a thousand words.

[image]